# I get this message when trying to use the command modprode, bash: modprobe: command not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, osdev

How do I install modprobe? I have already installed kmod using apt-get. I'm using Debian 8. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run the command `modprobe` as root , type :

```
su -
```

Enter your root password then run `modprobe` , or install and configure `sudo`

```
sudo modprobe module_name
```